# How to fix memory spike Cloud SQL (MYSQL) in GCP

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

[![MYSQL memory spike][1]][1]

Hi All, we use Cloud SQL (MYSQL) in GCP, more than last 2 weeks the memory increased, my question why the spike not decreased again, the trend now is flat. how do I check in detail the causes and how do I fix it ?

Comment: can you share and screenshot of the chart with his title? How many GB of memory does your instance have?

Comment: Hi J.A its memory chart, and I have 60 GB of RAM

Comment: If you are using temporary tables to handle information, these reside in the memory, in this mysql document are described which are the most common configurations that causing a high memory usage

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-use.html –

Answer (score 1):

I think that because your MySQL data is greater 48G, that‘s why the spike not decreased again

Comment: Hi @jasondayee correct data more than 48G but what's relation with memory ?

Comment: I think the display of the graph is the Storage usage ,not Memory usage @Khalid